# ChartJS - Line chart: Render background from Y min negative value like from Y zero value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

Now line chart renders the background like this (base scheme):

[Real case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Fzp.png)

But will be great if there is a way to render it like this (base scheme):

[Expected case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jfsE.png)

I will be very grateful for your help

I don't know even a direction where I need to dive

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.